# `auto` making a new variable instance each time?

Tags: c++, auto

I'm wondering if using `auto`, or anything other like declaring a variable/iterator/CallItWhatIsMoreAppropriate) will create an instance of that item each time? An example will make things clear:

```
void my_fun (std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> & my_map) {

    std::string search_str;

    cin >> search_str;

    while (search_str != "something") {

        //Does the next line create an extra overhead each time?
        auto search = my_map.find(search_str);

        if (search != my_map.end())
        {
            std::cout << "found \n";

            //I should be able to modify the element inside the map here.

        } else {
            my_map.insert( {search_str, search_str});
        }

        cin >> search_str;

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no overhead for using `auto`, and you should always define variables where they can be properly initialised.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I thought it was an important issue declaring variables only once needed and then using that instance, especially declarations are inside a loop that can run up to millions or even billions of times.

Comment: "Using `auto`" doesn't mean anything here.  `auto` is just a substitute for a type name.  What you really are asking about is the consequences of declaring a _local variable_ inside a loop.   Your `search` is a local variable.  It's not because you used `auto` in its declaration; It's because of _where_ you declared it.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance you should pass mymap by reference.

Comment: @manni66 It was for example purposes, but yes I should be consistent, fixed.

Comment: Note `auto` will never be deduced as a reference, references needs to be explicitly written

Comment: @PasserBy do you mean as other described like: `const auto &` or something else? I thought by all the comments in this question that `auto` is like a pointer that will point to the item I'm looking for (so no need for explicit reference `&` )

Comment: You need to read up on iterator/pointer semantics and what it's relation is to references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this particular code:

```
while (search_str != "something") {

     //Does the next line create an extra overhead each time?
     auto search = my_map.find(search_str);
```

if you mean if there is extra overhead vs:

```
  while (search_str != "something") {
        //Does the next line create an extra overhead each time?
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator search = my_map.find(search_str);
```

no there is no difference at all, compiler just deduces type for you. If you asking if declaring iterator outside of loop:

```
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator search;
  while (search_str != "something") {
        search = my_map.find(search_str);
        ...
```

would make it more efficient, it is theoretically possible (on some broken compiler) but I hardly doubt there would be any. And code readability is more important here as variant with declaring variable inside loop would make it cleaner and more readable.

Note change `search` type either to `const auto &` or more explicit `const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::iterator &` also very unlikely to make it more efficient in this case.

Comment: If I want to make modifications to the element inside the map what should I use? (const would make it uneditable, right? )

Comment: @AnnaK. you seem to  misunderstand what `std::unordered_map::find()` returns. It is not element itself but iterator. Look at it as a kind of pointer. So if you declare iterator const that would mean you cannot change iterator itself (for example to make to point to another element) but that would not prevent to change element to which it points to.

Comment: @AnnaK. to make it simple - iterators designed to be small and efficient, so declare iterator inside loop (either through `auto` or explicitly) is perfectly fine in this case and would not create additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. E.g., use `const auto&` or `auto&&` to declare a reference in case you want to avoid creating a copy of the object.

However, iterators have little overhead and are usually passed by value.

More importantly, you are passing the parameter `my_map` by value. Passing by value will prevent any changes to the container to be visible from outside the function (you're editing a copy). Pass by reference to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: `find` returns an iterator by value, so `auto&` will just create a const reference bound to a temporary. There's no benefit of using `auto&` here. edit: actually it doesn't even seem to compile (`invalid initialization of non-const reference ... from an rvalue ...`)

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I updated to use `const auto&`. My intention was to give a generic example , not the exact answer in this instance. I also explicitly explained that iterators are best passed _by value_ in my answer.

Comment: Why not use `auto&&` instead? :)

Comment: Note: I pass the map to the function just to make simple example that anyone could pass a map already filled with data. The true question is about declaring auto (or anything else that could take time) inside a loop that can run for a very long time (millions to billions of times).

Comment: Actually in this case using `const auto &` would not change "overhead" at all, so answer "yes" is incorrect. Again in this particular case.

Comment: @Slava The question reads "_I'm wondering if using `auto` ... will create an instance of that item each time?_". Not if "overhead" is greater compared to `const auto&`.

Comment: @Snps sorry I was not clear, I mean using `const auto &` in this case does not change anything in efficiency and does not prevent of creating a variable.

Comment: @Slava You're right. But it was never my intention to show that. I simply answered the question.

Comment: @Snps problem is your answer in this simple form is misleading, OP may think that to change `search` type to `const auto &` or `auto &&` would make it more efficient. And your explanation about iterators does not make it clear. In this particular case does not really matter what type `find()` returns iterator or big structure, `const autho &` would just exrtend life of temporary. So your answer is incorrect in this particular case.